# Aplicar um transform com perspectiva

Tags: android, imagem

Gostaria de fazer a seleção por perspectiva em um `imageview`.

Onde eu seleciono os 4 cantos da imagem e faço o recorte, seguindo essa ideia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei o dia todo e encontrei pouca coisa, encontrei esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627408/apply-a-perspective-transform-without-rotating) com a solução, só que para *ios*:

E encontrei alguma coisa relacionada a [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321307/image-perspective-transform-using-android-opencv).

Porém nenhum deles me ajudou, eu precisaria de algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde eu tire a foto, escolho os 4 cantos para recorte na proporção e salvo a imagem.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Leonardo, achei isto, usando OpenCV e detecção automática. Será que ajuda ou você prefere "recortar mesmo de acordo com os pontos marcados pelo usuário"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179805/rectangle-detection-using-opencv-in-android

Comment: Fala Mateus, o ideal seria que o usuário pudesse escolher os 4 pontos, pois ele irá tirar uma foto de uma prova, e depois selecionar os pontos e deixar só a prova na imagem, sem pedaços da mesa, por exemplo.

Comment: Leonardo, então você terá mesmo que implementar alguma customizada com o SurfaceView algo parecido com isso: http://adblogcat.com/a-camera-preview-with-a-bounding-box-like-google-goggles/

Comment: Fala Mateus, valeu pela dica cara! Consegui encontrar esse link e consegui fazer o efeito com a lib do OpenCV: https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo